# Copia e escrita de imagem lança java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!

Tags: java

Criei um algoritmo para percorrer uma árvore de diretórios e espelhar seu conteúdo. A exceção ocorre quando o programa entra em um diretório com 400 imagens. Ele faz as cópias das imagens até chegar em uma imagem por volta de 320 e lança a seguinte exceção, no metodo copiaArquivo, condicional isImagemJPG:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriter(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
at Main.copiaArquivo(Main.java:53)
at Main.entraDiretorio(Main.java:44)
at Main.entraDiretorio(Main.java:42)
at Main.entraDiretorio(Main.java:42)
at Main.entraDiretorio(Main.java:42)
at Main.main(Main.java:31)
```

O código é o seguinte:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Main {

private static File raizDiretorio;
private static File raizDiretorioCP;
private static String caminho = "D:\\Ultimate Collection\\info\\xyz\\";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    raizDiretorio = new File(caminho);
    raizDiretorioCP = new File(caminho + "copia\\");
    raizDiretorioCP.mkdir();

    File[] files = raizDiretorio.listFiles();

    entraDiretorio(files);

}

private static void entraDiretorio(File[] files) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory() && !file.getAbsolutePath().equals(raizDiretorioCP.getAbsolutePath())) {
            File[] listSubDiretorio = file.listFiles();
            file = new File(preparaCaminhoFileSaida(file));
            System.out.println("Criando diretorio " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            file.mkdir();
            entraDiretorio(listSubDiretorio);
        } else if (file.isFile() && !file.getAbsolutePath().equals(raizDiretorioCP.getAbsolutePath())) {
            copiaArquivo(file);
        }
    }
}

private static void copiaArquivo(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String caminhoSaida = preparaCaminhoFileSaida(file);
    if (isImagemJPG(file)) {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);
        System.out.println("Copiando imagem de :" + file.getPath() + "\n para: " + caminhoSaida);
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File(caminhoSaida));

    } else

    {

        File outFile = new File(caminhoSaida);
        if (!outFile.exists() && outFile.isDirectory())
            outFile.mkdir();
        System.out.println("Copiando arquivo: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        OutputStream ou = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(ou);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

        String texto = "";
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String linha = reader.readLine();
        while (linha != null) {
            texto += linha;
            linha = reader.readLine();
        }

        texto = texto.replaceAll("nomealeatorio", "");

        bw.write(texto);
        bw.close();

    }

}

private static boolean isImagemJPG(File file) {
    return file.getName().endsWith(".jpg");
}

private static String preparaCaminhoFileSaida(File file) throws IOException {
    String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
    path = path.replace(caminho, raizDiretorioCP.getCanonicalPath() + "\\");
    return path;
}
}
```

Se eu colocar uma condicional para pular esta foto que lança a exceção o programa continua mas depois de algumas fotos ele lança novamente a excessão em outra foto. Já verifiquei a extensão das fotos e todas elas são jpg. Não há nenhum outro tipo de arquivo no diretorio.
Estou sem entender por que até certo ponto o algoritmo funciona e depois não.

Comment: Já verificou se esses arquivos que lançam a excepção são mesmo imagens. Podem ter a extensão *jpg* e não serem.

Comment: Alguns outros pontos que não cabem diretamente na resposta. Seu código está carregado de métodos e variáveis estáticas (o que não é um bom sinal). Além disso, me parece que você está reinventando a roda... Dê uma olhada na classe [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html), existe bastante coisa pronta para caminhar arvores de arquivos e fazer operações simples de leitura / escrita / cópia.

Comment: Se a ideia é copiar um diretório inteiro dê uma olhada em [`FileUtils.copyDirectory`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectory(java.io.File,%20java.io.File)) da biblioteca [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Da documentação de [`ImageIO.read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-java.io.File-):

> Retorna uma `BufferedImage` como resultado da decodificação do `File` fornecido com um `ImageReader` escolhido automaticamente dentre aqueles atualmente registrados. Se nenhum `ImageReader` registrado afirma ser capaz de ler a stream resultante, **`null` é retornado** [enfase minha].

`img` está nulo para alguns de seus arquivos `jpg` (você pode confirmar isso imprimindo `img`). Provavelmente isso ocorre pois o método `read` não está conseguindo ler alguns dos arquivos. Não consigo te precisar exatamente o que está fazendo o ImageIO engasgar, mas sei que essa classe [não se comporta bem com CMYK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552838/reading-jpegs-in-java) e [alguns perfis de cores ICC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16149357/664577).

Dito isso, eu não entendi porque você está tentando "interpretar" os arquivos se o objetivo é só copiá-los de um lugar para o outro. Caso você não pretenda alterar os arquivos um método de cópia direta como o abaixo deve resolver o seu problema:

```
Files.copy(file.toPath(), new File(caminhoSaida).toPath());
```

Comment: Obrigado, não conhecia a classe Files e ela resolveu este problema e mais alguns outros!E realmente este código precisou de uma refatoração. Obrigada pelas dicas!